# Both parameterized and sharing recources test in googletest

Tags: c++, templates, googletest, static-members

Using googletest framework  I try to create an inherited fixture class in order to make a both parameterized and sharing recources test.

```
class FixtDBadminConnShared : public ::testing::Test {
  public:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {
      shared_conn_ = new ::DB::DB_connection();
    }
    static void TearDownTestCase() {
      delete shared_conn_;
    }
    static ::DB::DB_connection * shared_conn_;
    };
::DB::DB_connection * FixtDBadminConnShared::shared_conn_ = nullptr;

class FixtDBadminConnExec :public FixtDBadminConnShared, public ::testing::TestWithParam<string> 
  {
  protected:
    using FixtDBadminConnShared::SetUpTestCase;
    using FixtDBadminConnShared::TearDownTestCase;

    void SetUp() override {
      query_ = GetParam();
    }
    string query_;
  };
```

Trying to call the test:

```
TEST_P(FixtDBadminConnExec, SelectWithoutParam) {
 //do smth
}
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(QueriesOrbital0param, FixtDBadminConnExec,
::testing::Values( string{ "SELECT * from my_table;" }));
```

I get the next error

```
Error   C2594   'return': ambiguous conversions from 'FixtDBadminConnExec_SelectWithoutParam_Test *' to 'testing::Test *'   gtest_mytest    e:\libs\googletest\googletest\include\gtest\internal\gtest-param-util.h 415
```

Here is a part of **gtest-param-util.h** with 415 line on  *return new TestClass()*:

```
template <class TestClass>
class ParameterizedTestFactory : public TestFactoryBase {
 public:
  typedef typename TestClass::ParamType ParamType;
  explicit ParameterizedTestFactory(ParamType parameter) :
      parameter_(parameter) {}
  virtual Test* CreateTest() {
    TestClass::SetParam(&parameter_);
    return new TestClass();
  }

 private:
  const ParamType parameter_;

  GTEST_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN_(ParameterizedTestFactory);
};
```

So, I guess that problem could be also that I want to use both a parameterized test (TEST_P macros) and a test with shared resources (TEST_F macros ). How can I do it, if can?

Answer (score 9):

Your problem here is that TestWithParam<> inherits from testing::Test and there is an ambiguous conversion. Instead, inherit from WithParamInterface<>